# org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'UserEntity' JPA and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I've got Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'UserEntity' exception. Here is my method from JpaRepository implementation witch caused it:

```
@Query(value = """
        SELECT u FROM UserEntity u WHERE
            u.id NOT LIKE :user_id AND
            u.is_account_confirmed = true AND
            u.id NOT IN (SELECT f.friends AS fri FROM UserEntity f WHERE fri.id = :user_id)""")
List<UserEntity> findAllNonFriendUsers(@Param("user_id") String id);
```

IntelliJ also highlightet the UserEntity class name as "Could not resolve". I saw some similar questions and I have proper @Entity annotation on UserEntity class and also JPA Facet in project structure (set on Hibernate) exists. I also have spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency of course.

Does someone see a mistake? I don't know very well JPA so the mistake may be really trivial.

Edit:
If I've removed a `name` argument from @Entity annotation in `UserEntity`, exception disappeard. It also works if I replace class name with entity name, but not if entity name contains `-` sign. Is there a possibility to not changing it?

Comment: There is no name argument shown in; maybe show your entity next time. JPQL requires the entity name be used and it is a convenience that the entity name defaults to the class name when it is undefined which is why what you've shown works when you don't define an entity name different from UserEntity. You can define any entity name you want (within the naming rules of the spec) - but why would you if you aren't going to use it? Different names are useful when you have the same class names but in different packages mapped as entities, as the names have to be unique within the context

Comment: I have a few entities with same class names, that is why I add a custom name to the entity

Comment: The query string has no context at all of which java class it operates on, so you need to use the entity name in your queries to identify which 'UserEntity' you are operating on.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have the following in place:

- `UserEntity` is annotated with an `@Entity` annotation
- `@EntityScan("com.example.entities")` is pointing to the correct package containing the entities

Comment: I already have @Entity annotation as I wrote in my question.

Comment: @MateuszWołek updated the answer. Do you have `EntityScan`?

Answer (score 0):

The `@Entity` name attribute is used in the JPA Query, if you omit the name attribute the class name will be taken.
If your database table name differs from entity/class name you need to use the `@Table` anntotation.
E.g.

```
@Table(name = "EntityTable")
@Entity(name = "UserEntity")
public class MyUserEntity
```

EntityTable -> database table name
UserEntity -> used in your @Query